# PHP: POST method works in DocumentRoot, but not in Aliases (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: php, forms, apache

I am completely new to PHP.

I am running the code to test the POST method in form submission. 
If I run the .php files from DocumentRoot (/var/www/html/), then POST works fine (transfers the data to main.php from welcome.php successfully). 
I added my alias directory to the alias.conf file too, so I can run them seperately, successfully from the browser.

However, when I run those same .php files to test POST method in my alias directory, it gives 404 error (in Firefox) or the main.php file with empty POST variable (in Chrome).
I searched the web and found different answers, but I could not find the relevant one to my case. I think it must be some apache configuration issue, but I am not sure what it is. What should I do to fix the POST method for my alias directory? Thank you in advance.
Regards.

Here is the welcome.php file:

```html
<html>
<body>

<form action="main.php" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /><br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the main.php file:

```html
<html>
<body>
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the part of my alias.conf file:

```
    ...
    Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/apache2/icons/"

    <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/icons">
            Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /HWeb/ "/home/userio/HWeb/"

    <Directory "/home/userio/HWeb">
            Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ...
```

Here is the apache2.conf file:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: If you think that the problem is caused by the apache configuration, then why you haven't put into your post apache conf files, and instead just some common php snippets?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am putting the alias file now.

Comment: ... and make sure you've not set invalid <base> in HTML http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp . Are you using htaccess and mod_rewrite?

Comment: No, I didn't use any of them. I only installed apache and php based on some guidelines, that's all.

Comment: Also, the program works fine with GET method.

Comment: Added apache2.conf file

Comment: Did you solve that issue?

Comment: No, I couldn't yet.  I am just working on only /var/www/html for now.

Comment: My exact question is what configuration attribute or other "mystery"  causes POST method to work in /var/www/html, but to fail in any other alias directory.